# How to change desktop background if "setting is disabled by an administrator"?

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop-customization

I use Windows 7 in an office. Over the weekend, our corporate overlords replaced everyone's desktop backgrounds (holiday photos, landscapes, family portraits) with company colours--lurid bright green. How can I change it?

I tried 'Personalize' but the desktop background setting is locked.

> One or more of the settings is disabled by an administrator.

Is there anyway I can bypass the restriction? I have local admin rights on the computer.

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: It's critical to the functioning of the office that all screen backgrounds be identical.  You wouldn't want to degrade the performance of the whole organization by changing your screen background, would you?  :-)

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/287436/wallpaper-in-windows-7-locked-down-by-domain-group-policy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved. Located lurid green background at `C:\Windows\banner.bmp`. Renamed background of my choice in Pictures to `banner.bmp`, then copied it to `C:\Windows`. Restarted explorer.exe, now shows my background.